# Running Application after installing from .cab

Tags: windows-ce, cab, compact-framework2.0

i need to know a way to run my application on a Windows CE 6.0 Device after installing from a .cab file. 
The application is placed in the autostart folder.. so i need either a warm reboot or a direct start after installing from .cab

Can somebody give me a solution for that problem?

greetings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a [custom setup.dll to the installer package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924308.aspx).  Launch your app in `Install_Exit` by calling the [`CreateProcess` API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee488927%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx).  You can assemble the path if it's user changeable by using the `pszInstallDir` parameter that's passed in.

Comment: how can i execute my application from the Install_Exit function? i mean what i need to add there? Thanks